# Within AEM - what's the use of the "Form Chooser Servlet"?

Tags: aem

While looking at the AEM 6.x security checklist I saw the hint on the Form Chooser Servlet. https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/administering/using/security-checklist.html#main-pars_text_1734142030

I wonder what this servlet is good for? For what is it used? Can it be just deactivated completely? Are other servlets or features within AEM using this feature and build on its availability?
While searching for a description, I could only find some code (https://github.com/ooyala/Ooyala-AdobeCQ/blob/master/ui/src/content/jcr_root/libs/foundation/src/impl/src/main/java/com/day/cq/wcm/foundation/forms/impl/FormChooserServlet.java), but not the actual use case behind the feature.

Given the high risk of receiving a DoS when this servlet is actively listening, I'd think of rather deactivating it.

Somebody here able to shed some light on this?